# “The dangerous of” vs. “The danger of “

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Can an adjective be followed by **of** that regarded as possessive but not the one that is a part of adjective.

> - 1) Do you know the **dangerous** of smoking cigarettes?

Usually I read always such as this following structure.

> - 2) Do you know the **danger** of smoking cigarettes?

However, i have noticed such aforementioned sentences (1) in books.

The real text i Read was for Sigmund Freud

> - through the [satisfying](https://books.google.ca/books?id=m4jrCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT7&dq=%E2%80%9Cthrough%20the%20satisfying%20of%E2%80%9D%20freud%20a%20general%20introduction&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAt5KP7rzfAhXG6oMKHXqvAGEQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9Cthrough%20the%20satisfying%20of%E2%80%9D%20freud%20a%20general%20introduction&f=false) of sexual instincts...

Comment: Pretty sure the first one is grammatically incorrect. Can you mentions the source(s) where you've encountered the same?

Comment: I have just provided two sources above in my question! @CinCout

Comment: *The dangerous of* is ungrammatical. Any book that published it didn't have an author or editor who caught the error. It almost certainly was meant to be *the dangers of*, and the wrong word was typed by mistake.

Comment: I have just added the real text i have read in Sigmund’s book @JasonBassford

Comment: Unlike "dangerous", "satisfying" is a gerund-participle that can be used as an adjective and, as in your last example, as a noun (gerundial noun). That it is a noun is evident from the fact that it has the determiner "the" and it has an _of_ phrase as complement. It can also be modified by an adjective, cf. "the occasional satisfying of sexual instincts.

Comment: @JasonBassford Might there be a special case in which "the dangerous" like a standalone noun phrase can be used? For example, "the dangerous of the acid is well known to chemists"

Comment: @SinK The following would be fine: *The few, the proud, and the dangerous.* But *the dangerous of the acid* can never be grammatical. Instead, it should be *the **dangerousness** of the acid* (or *the **danger** of the acid*). However, you could say *the **most** dangerous of the* ***acids***. It's also okay without *of*: *The dangerous acid.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“The dangerous of smoking” is unidiomatic to me as a native speaker of American English. While there are some cases where you can use an adjective like a noun, it’s not possible here.

To confirm this, I searched the [corpus of contemporary American English](https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) for `* dangerous of _nn*` (where the first asterisk matches any word and the last part matches any noun) and the results I got were all for “the most dangerous of [plural noun]”, which is a different structure that *is* acceptable.

Sometimes mistakes happen, which is the only explanation I have for the occurrence in the first source. In the case of the second source there are several errors in the small part I read:

- “let the child knows” (should be “know”)
- “a Must” (should be lowercase)

---

To answer your real question, “satisfying” is a gerund (which work the same way as nouns), so it works in the context.

Comment: I have just added the real text i have read in my question

Comment: Can satisfaction (noun)  be a substitute for the “satisfying” gerund here with no change in meaning?